# mysql database column issue

Tags: mysql, database

Create a list of all players and the fees they pay.  The football league is looking to increase fees by 15%.  Show that column in your list.  When complete your output should look like the following.  Note:  your spacing may be a little different.  This output is formatted to be smaller.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmN6D.png - Question with the format required
[enter image description here][1]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJNVS.png - Picture of the table that is going to be used. The table name is 'playerrec'

I know that you will have to use an alias for the column Fee it would be renamed to Increased Fee, but where I am getting stuck at is that I don't know what to do for the New Fee since it isn't a column that is existing. I've already thought about creating column, but I looked at my teachers lectures and it seems we won't be getting into that for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can operate on a column in your SELECT clause using arithmetic operators.

If you were looking to get the base fees off the playerrec table, you could do so by simply selecting the column

```
SELECT pr.Fee
FROM playerrec AS pr
```

If you were looking to get, say, *double* the normal fee, you could do so like this:

```
SELECT (2 * pr.Fee) AS DoubledFee
FROM playerrec AS pr
```

Here you're computing a new column and aliasing it as 'DoubledFee'. This does not change the underlying data nor add a column to the table. If you want a comparison, you could select both together

```
SELECT Fee, (2 * pr.Fee) AS DoubledFee
...
```

For more, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/multiply-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

As a bonus, the microsoft example includes a 15% change